# How to get HTML onclick attribute in iOS uiwebview

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, uiwebview

Here is HTML code

```
<a href="#" title="bagging" onclick="zergling.bagging('good','job');">
```

If click this code,

How to get "zergling.bagging('good','job');" in iOS uiwebview?

Comment: Do you want to call this function through iOS? or, you want to know the output of the function in iOS? or, your function doesn't work on UIWebView?

Comment: I want to know the output of the function in iOS

Comment: The best way to do this is URL Rewriting.. you need to modify the function and append the output in the url as when you call the function it will append `#`, then reading the url using UIWebView delegate function you can substring the url and get the result.